# Dockerfile can't see local file or private nuget server

Tags: c#, visual-studio, docker, nuget

I am trying to start my .net core web api on container tech. using docker.

Environments=Windows 10,Visual Studio

Docker version:

> Client:
>
> Version:       17.12.0-ce
>
> API version:   1.35
>
> Go version:    go1.9.2
>
> Git commit:    c97c6d6
>
> Built: Wed Dec 27 20:05:22 2017
>
> OS/Arch:       windows/amd64
>
> Server:
>
> Engine:
>
> Version:      17.12.0-ce
>
> API version:  1.35 (minimum version 1.12)
>
> Go version:   go1.9.2
>
> Git commit:   c97c6d6
>
> Built:        Wed Dec 27 20:12:29 2017
>
> OS/Arch:      linux/amd64
>
> Experimental: true

My Nuget.Config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
<packageSources>


<add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" 
protocolVersion="3" />


<add key="Private" 
value="http://My_Private_Nuget_Server" />


</packageSources>
<packageRestore>
<add key="enabled" value="True" />
<add key="automatic" value="True" />
</packageRestore>
<bindingRedirects>
<add key="skip" value="False" />
</bindingRedirects>
<packageManagement>
<add key="format" value="0" />
<add key="disabled" value="True" />
</packageManagement>


<apikeys>
<add key="https://www.nuget.org" value="Some_Long_Value" />
</apikeys>


<disabledPackageSources />
</configuration>
```

My Dockerfile:

```
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore-build:2.0 AS build-env
WORKDIR /app

# Copy csproj and restore as distinct layers
COPY *.csproj ./
RUN dotnet restore

# Copy everything else and build
COPY . ./
RUN dotnet publish -c Release -o out

# Build runtime image
FROM microsoft/aspnetcore:2.0
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=build-env /app/out .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "MailAlertWebApiWithEF.dll"]
```

I' am using Linux Container on windows 10 machine. I have .net core project on Visual Studio 17. When ı add docker support and run from VS 17 everything works fine. API stands up inside a container.But don't work when i close the VS. However When ı try to customize my dockerfile to make my image and container independent from VS. It gives error because of a private `.dll`.

In my project ı have a .`dll`  from my private nuget server. When ı tried without my private `.dll` ı can create image. But ı need that `.dll`. Docker give me this error:

> MailAlertWebApiWithEF.csproj : error NU1101: Unable to find package
>   WebApi.Utils. No packages exist with this id in source(s):
>   nuget.org

I searched this error. The source of problem seems like Nuget.Config file. But it seems good to me because i can see me private nuget server in there. When ı searched the solutions arrows always on linux machines but ı use windows.

1-)So if i can start  my project with VS 17 , then my nuget.config file is in correct form. It can see my private nuget server. Right? Then why not docker don't see it?

Please help

Comment: I found the problem but not solution. 
'Dotnet Restore' command don't install one of my private package but install others from my private server.

Comment: `Dotnet Restore' command don't install one of my private package ` Is that package .NET Framework library? If yes, the command line dotnet  restore unable to resolve .NET Framework libraries, you can try to use `nuget restore`. https://github.com/dotnet/cli/issues/3199

Comment: It was all .net standart library and compatibla with .net core.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

In order for a `dotnet` command running inside a container to find your custom feeds, the `nuget.config` file must also be copied to the container.

To do this, add a `nuget.config` file with your private feed to your project folder and add an additional `COPY` step that copies this file to the container.

Example (Dockerfile):

```
WORKDIR ...
COPY NuGet.Config /
COPY ... ...
```

Comment: COPY NuGet.Config / this fails on mine even though the file is there

Comment: For those who have configured Visual Studio to use the `PackageReference` format where packages are cached at the machine level, the `nuget.config` file is likely to be in `$HOME\AppData\Roaming\NuGet` (as a Windows path)

Comment: I just discovered that nuget.config (the file name) is case sensitive on Linux, which isn't so surprising really but caught me out!

Answer (score 47):

for those who have landed here as they were using **private repositories** or **custom nuget feeds** and ***RUN dotnet restore***  is **failing** ,then here is what you can do :

**Applicable especially if** : your NuGet.Config contains the private repo endpoint and credentials , then

1. copy your system's NuGet.Config in project folder at same root level where .csproject is.
2. now in docker file put these statements just before you try to restore package:

   `COPY ./NuGet.Config ./`
3. after that , append the config file location in dotnet restore command like this :

   `RUN dotnet restore <CS_project_name>.csproj --configfile ./NuGet.Config`
4. Now do rest of the thing which you wanted to do .
5. just at the end before entry point or before copying to other container(in case of multistage build) , it is good idea to **remove NuGet.Config**,as we don’t want that to be available in pod/container to be seen

`RUN rm ./NuGet.Config`

**[Update]** like mentioned at https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4413#issuecomment-483920015

if we use the following copy command to put it in root of file system

```
COPY ./NuGet.Config /nuget.config
```

then we dont need to specify the location of config file during `dotnet restore`

Comment: It will be worth noting that `RUN rm ./NuGet.Config` will not work on windows, instead you will need to use `RUN del -f "./NuGet.Config"`

Comment: @devnsyde , basically we are trying to delete this nuget।config from build container so that even if someone download and do exec inside image he should not be able to know credentials for private repo,thus this *rm* command actually runs inside Linux container OS and works well without any issue, we are not deleting anything from windows

Comment: I know the answer was for someone running linux but I landed on this page when trying to figure out why `RM` wasn't working in my docker file, it was because I was on a windows container. Now when people from windows land on this answer they can see to use `DEL` instead.

Comment: This answer helped me TREMENDOUSLY thanks to the instruction to append the config file location to the `dotnet restore` command. I had no idea this was necessary :)

Comment: In extension to that , this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/63938470 from 0909EM  and here at https://github.com/NuGet/Home/issues/4413#issuecomment-483920015 , also  helps by putting the file in location : `/root/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config`  or  `/nuget.config ` where docker will by default see it.

Comment: A `RUN rm ./NuGet.Config` will **not** remove the file from the image as a whole. It will stay visible at the lower layers. A new `RUN` layer will add a layer on top with that file removed, but that's it. So this is insecure: the file isn't *actually* removed.

Answer (score 23):

You can add the private nuget through dotnet command, without the need to link to nuget.config file.

```
COPY *.csproj ./  

RUN dotnet nuget add source <source-value-of-nuget> -n <name> 

RUN dotnet restore
```

Comment: for some bizarre reason, docker couldn't find my nuget.config file no matter how I would address it but your solution worked very well, thank you for saving my time after spending 2 hours to solve it..

Comment: I had the same issue where my copy was not working. Was = " COPY nuget.config . " / IS = " COPY /Source/nuget.config . " Where my solution is in the root directory and my project + nuget.config files are in subfolder "Source"

Answer (score 7):

Copying the `Nuget.Config` to the solution or project folder will work if your 'private nuget feed' is accessible via a url.
But if the private feed is a local folder used as a nuget source, this approach will still fail with an error that the folder is outside the build context or simply because the Windows path does not get resolved by the Docker build process.

e.g. if you `Nuget.Config` has something like this:

```
  <packageSources>
    <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
    <add key="My Local" value="C:\dev\nuget-packages" />
  </packageSources>
```

the Docker context will not resolve `C:\dev\nuget-packages`

It's tempting to just give up on building within docker and just pre-publish the compiled solution and build the image from that...

But another workaround, requiring a few more steps, is also possible:
run `dotnet restore` *before* running the `docker-compose` command, and use the `--packages` option to save the restored packages to the solution folder
e.g.

`dotnet-restore C:\slnfolder\myproj\myapp.csproj --packages C:\slnfolder\packages`

(This could be wrapped in a single powershell script along with the `docker-compose` command.)

Then in the Dockerfile (used by `docker-compose` to build the image), assuming context is the solution folder and `WORKDIR` is `'/src'`

`COPY packages/. packages/.`

and modify the Dockerfile restore line to

`RUN dotnet restore "myproj/myapp.csproj" -s /src/packages -s https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json`

Answer (score 3):

Stumbled across this while looking for another nuget question/answer...

To restore from within docker, as mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54017310/843387) copy a nuget.config file to the container first, I'd suggest you place this in `/root/.nuget/NuGet` folder and use a multistage Dockerfile, that way, you don't need to worry about removing it.

If it helps, this is my setup...

```
--nuget.config
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="PrivateFeed" value="https://private.nuget.feed.net/" />
  </packageSources>
  <packageSourceCredentials>
    <PrivateFeed>
      <add key="Username" value="username" />
      <add key="ClearTextPassword" value="plaintext_password" />
    </PrivateFeed>
  </packageSourceCredentials>
</configuration>
```

Multi-stage Dockerfile...

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1.201 as sdk-build
WORKDIR /app

# Skip extraction of XML documentation for nuget packages
ENV NUGET_XMLDOC_MODE=skip

# We'll copy the nuget config file to the right place
# which should mean it doesn't get copied to our deployed containers
# and we can just call 'dotnet restore' with specifying a config file
COPY ./Nuget.Config /root/.nuget/NuGet/NuGet.Config

# Make use of cached layers, by only doing a restore when the config changes
COPY ./*.sln ./**/*.csproj ./

# Then within a RUN command to copy them to the right folders.
RUN for file in $(ls *.csproj); do mkdir -p ${file%.*}/ && mv $file ${file%.*}/; done \
    && dotnet restore

# Copy the source code
COPY . .

# Now do a build/publish here
RUN dotnet publish "./project/project.csproj" --output /app/output


FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1.2
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=sdk-build /app/output ./
ENTRYPOINT ["./project"]
```

Answer (score 1):

This problem need not have a complex solution.
For your "dotnet publish" to work it needs to be aware of where to look for NuGet packages and the NuGet packages should be available at that location.

So you only need to copy your folder containing NuGet packages to the container and then tell the build utility where to look for using the following command

```
RUN dotnet nuget add source /repo/nuget-local-source -n local-repo
```

Comment: Dockerfile commands (simplified for copy-paste):
`COPY "nugets/" "/var/nugets/"`
`RUN dotnet nuget add source /var/nugets/`
I've used something like that in my case to not overcomplicate solution. Snippet was taken from another thread - there you can find more explanation: [local-nuget-source-doesnt-exist-when-building-for-docker](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72865046/local-nuget-source-doesnt-exist-when-building-for-docker)