# Nuget command fails in docker file but not when run manually

Tags: docker, nuget, containers, dockerfile

I am trying to configure a container to run my build.  (It is a windows core container.)

When I run a nuget command in the docker file, it fails.  But when I connect powershell to the container, it runs fine.

This is the command in question:

```
nuget sources Add -Name "Common Source" -Source http://CompanyPackages/nuget/Common
```

I run it from the docker file like this:

```
RUN nuget sources Add -Name "Common Source" -Source http://CompanyPackages/nuget/Common
```

And get the following error:

```
sources: invalid arguments.
```

However, when I take the container and start it using:

```
docker run -it agent:v1
```

Then run the same command inside the container:

```
nuget sources Add -Name "Common Source" -Source http://CompanyPackages/nuget/Common
```

The result is:

```
Package Source with Name: Common added successfully.
```

**What would cause it to fail in the dockerfile and not in the container?**

Note:

In case it is useful, here is my full docker file:

```
 FROM sixeyed/msbuild:netfx-4.5.2-webdeploy AS build-agent
 SHELL ["powershell"]

 RUN nuget sources Add -Name "Common Source" -Source http://CompanyPackages/nuget/Common
```

Comment: Maybe it's something stupidly simple like the escaping the parentheses or using the braces notation of run (`RUN ["nuget", "sources", "Add" ...]`)?

Comment: Are arguments for nuget case sensitive? Do you maybe have to use "`nuget sources add`" instead of "`nuget sources Add`"?

Comment: Another reason can be that the `nuget.config` is not in place yet like described @ https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48821991/dockerfile-cant-see-local-file-or-private-nuget-server. Maybe do `COPY NuGet.Config /` first?

Comment: Maybe `SHELL ["powershell", "-command"]` as in the [docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#shell).

Comment: Could you post your `nuget.config`? That's the first place to look for a problem.

Answer (score 3):

I tried it and got it working like this:

If you change the content of your `Dockerfile` like this:

```
FROM sixeyed/msbuild:netfx-4.5.2-webdeploy AS build-agent
SHELL ["powershell"]
RUN ["nuget", "sources" , "Add", "-Name", "\"Common Source\"", "-Source" ,"http://CompanyPackages/nuget/common"]
```

And when you then run `docker build -t yourImageName .`

You end up with this:

```
Sending build context to Docker daemon  2.048kB
Step 1/3 : FROM sixeyed/msbuild:netfx-4.5.2-webdeploy AS build-agent
 ---> 0851a5b495a3
Step 2/3 : SHELL ["powershell"]
 ---> Running in 10082a1c45f8
Removing intermediate container 10082a1c45f8
 ---> c00b912c6a8f
Step 3/3 : RUN ["nuget", "sources" , "Add", "-Name", "\"Common Source\"", "-Source" ,"http://CompanyPackages/nuget/common"]
 ---> Running in 797b6c055928
Package Source with Name: "Common Source" added successfully.
Removing intermediate container 797b6c055928
 ---> 592db3be9f8b
Successfully built 592db3be9f8b
Successfully tagged nuget-tester:latest
```

Comment: the image was about 4 gig in download size and about 11 gig in extracted size o_O

Comment: I am going to award the bounty here because it was parameter related and this works.  For others who find this in the future, I also found that removing the space from the name of the source fixes the issue.  (so `-Name "Common Source"` changed to `-Name "CommonSource"`)