# Dotnet restore from Docker over VPN

Tags: docker, .net-core, nuget, docker-network

A build in a Docker container fails on dotnet restore, erroring on retrieving nuget packages from a private repo

`FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:2.2 AS build-env
...
RUN dotnet restore
  Retrying 'FindPackagesByIdAsyncCore' for source 'http://privaterepo.somedomain.com/FindPackagesById()?id='somepackagename'&semVerLevel=2.0.0'.
  Connection refused`

Ultimately the restore command fails when it can't retrieve the necessary packages

These packages on a private repo need to be accessed via VPN.  Building the solution works fine in Visual Studio but the build in the container always fails.  This may be happening because:

1. VS has retry logic for retrieving the packages on restore, the CL in a Docker container may not be as forgiving
2. May not be able to access repo from within the container due to the way the network is configured

My workaround is to copy the relevant locally cached packages (from C:\Users\username.nuget\packages ) to a packages folder on the root of the project and then add this line to the Dockerfile above the restore command:

`COPY packages /root/.nuget/packages`

This workaround allows the restore command to complete successfully but slows down the build substantially and puts potentially unecessary files in the build folder.  Is there a better solution?

You could run a [NuGet server in a Docker container](https://dotnetthoughts.net/running-a-nuget-server-on-docker/) but that's also overhead that is probably unecessary.

Comment: See here, this has already been covered:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48821991/dockerfile-cant-see-local-file-or-private-nuget-server

Comment: @Kris.J that doesn't really address my issue, I'm already copying over the nuget config file.  My issue is that restore can't access the private repos from within the build container

Comment: Your original post doesn't contain that information :)

Comment: Did you get to handle it?