# Unable to add local nuget package to Dockerfile

Tags: c#, docker, asp.net-core

I have created a dockerfile. In this file, there is a step to restore packages that solution has.

However, I am unable to get succeeded because of not finding local nuget package.

I try [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54017310) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63521182)

however, in both way, I get error : The local source '/src/C:\Users\okant\code-workspace\GringottsBank\packages' doesn't exist. error. I don't know why /src/ is coming.

Dockerfile content like that

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5001

ENV ASPNETCORE_URLS=http://+:5001

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build

WORKDIR /src

COPY . .

COPY ./NuGet.Config ./

RUN dotnet restore "./Gringotts.BankCustomer.Service/Gringotts.BankCustomer.Service.csproj"

WORKDIR "/src/Gringotts.BankCustomer.Service"

RUN dotnet build "Gringotts.BankCustomer.Service.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Gringotts.BankCustomer.Service.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "Gringotts.BankCustomer.Service.dll"]
```

NuGet.Config file like that

```
 <add key="GringottsLibrary" value="C:\Users\okant\code-workspace\GringottsBank\packages" />
```

and path: C:\Users\okant\AppData\Roaming\NuGet\NuGet.Config

And project structure like that

```
  Gringotts.BankCustomer.Contracts

  Gringotts.BankCustomer.Service

  Dockerfile

  NuGet.Config
```

Any help please, I really very appreciate it

Comment: It's going to be a problem that your Nuget.config file is an absolute Windows path. It seems that your dockerfile is making a Linux image, and it doesn't have access to the same file system as your host system unless you copy files over.

Comment: Is it possible to not use a nuget reference and instead use a project reference?

Comment: @gunr2171 It is not the only project that reference nuget package. So, I need to use it.

Answer (score 1):

In both solutions you linked in your question the solution requires you to copy the .csproj to same folder where you have the Nuget.Config. In your Dockerfile you are only copying the Nuget.Config and you have a slight misorder of steps

```html
WORKDIR /src

COPY . .

COPY ./NuGet.Config ./
```

You should have a similar structure to this if your using VSCODE or VS 2019-2022

```html
WORKDIR /src

COPY ["Gringotts.BankCustomer.Service/Gringotts.BankCustomer.Service.csproj", "Gringotts.BankCustomer.Service/"]

COPY ./NuGet.Config ./

RUN dotnet restore "./Gringotts.BankCustomer.Service/Gringotts.BankCustomer.Service.csproj"

COPY . .

WORKDIR "/src/Gringotts.BankCustomer.Service"

RUN dotnet build "Gringotts.BankCustomer.Service.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build
```