# Local NuGet source doesnt exist when building for Docker

Tags: .net, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, nuget-package-restore

I have 2 NuGet sources which are only simple local folders where im testing some Nuget Deployment. One is on my C Drive and the other on a Network share.
Im trying to build a Docker Image from the Dockerfile and it is giving me the error

> error NU1301: The local source '/src/C:\Users\dominik.essenhofer\Documents\Local Nuget Packages' doesn't exist.

Obviously this is wrong.

Here is my Dockerfile (which is mostly autogenerated)

```
#See https://aka.ms/containerfastmode to understand how Visual Studio uses this Dockerfile to build your images for faster debugging.

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 5051

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["TeamService/TeamService.csproj", "TeamService/"]
COPY ./NuGet.Config ./
RUN dotnet restore "TeamService/TeamService.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/TeamService"
RUN dotnet build "TeamService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "TeamService.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "TeamService.dll"]
```

The NuGet.Config file is in the same folder as the .sln file and contains all the NuGet sources i have configured.
Here is it's contents:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
    <packageSources>
        <add key="nuget.org" value="https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json" protocolVersion="3" />
        <add key="Local Packages" value="C:\Users\dominik.essenhofer\Documents\Local Nuget Packages" />
        <add key="UC Package Store" value="\\vierepo01\ucPackageStore\net-core" />
    </packageSources>
</configuration>
```

Obviously the Path that i tries to get the Nuget packages from is not correct. How can i fix this path so it can successfully restore the packages?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I ran into the same problems trying various methods to overcome to no vail.
There are two main issues :

1. When you run a dockerfile, it runs in a context.

   The context is the folder the command ran from, in VS case its one folder above the .csproj, 
   and (for security reasons apparently) you can't go up the folders hierarchy, only into folders in the context.
2. Containers is running on virtual networks, where each docker-compose gets its own network, so composes can't talk to each other and to standalone containers, but can talk to themselves.
   The default bridge network is for all standalone containers (composes cant reach it) but have DNS disabled.

   *I tried running a local NuGet feed (BaGet) on the same docker-compose, but dockerfile runtime is mapped to the default network, so I tried to run my feed on the default network, and without DNS I used the virtual IP and it worked, but who wants to work with IPs...*

Here are the solution I came with :

1. Create a script that copies your NuGet's to the same context as the dockerfile,
   and add a local store.

```bash
COPY "nugets/" "/var/nugets/"
RUN dotnet nuget add source /var/nugets/
```

2. As I wrote, run a standalone container of an open source NuGet feed, and use its IP (you can get a container IP by running the command `docker inspect [container_id]`
   and of course add it in the dockerfile

```bash
RUN dotnet nuget add source http://172.17.0.2/v3/index.json -n local.nuget
```

3. Run a local NuGet feed server, not on docker (the one I mentioned, BaGet, is running on dotnet) and address to it.
4. Open an organization in GitHub and use its services for private NuGet feed.

I'm currently rocking with option 3.
I find it shameful that I can't create a custom network with DNS, and attach my dockerfile and my NuGet feed to it, nor able to run my dockerfile on the same network as my compose, I'm aware of the security but this a compromise I'm willing to take and I'm being forced for policies I neither want or need right now.

Best of luck mate !